# jQuery Mobile - Bind Android "Next" Key

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making a phonegap application with jQuery Mobile.

Here the thing. I've got an input field like this one, at the end of fieldset :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  // Various fields
  <input type="number" id="txtMesure"/>
</div>
```

When I click on it with my Android device, it shows the numeric keyboard with a "Next" button, like this :

[image: Next button]

When I click on the Next button while filling the previous fields, it automaticaly focus the next field, but with this one, the last of the fieldset, it obviously does nothing.

Is there a way to bind an action when I click on this "Next" button ?

I've tried many events like *keyup, keydown, keypress, change, input* but the "Next" button never trigger any of these events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give [.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) a try. If there is nothing else to focus, maybe add an invisible input field; though this is quite a cheesy solution..

Comment: I tried this one too, but it doesn't worked. He was successfuly triggered when I clicked outside the field, but the "Next" key still did nothing.

Comment: And if you add an other input field with say opacity:0?

Comment: I didn't wanted to do something like this, but it worked so it's good atm. If someone has the same problem, i've bind the focus on the other field, where i put a little timeout before focusing the previous field (otherwise the device doesn't recognize the actual input you have focused). Thanks.